# Detecting if a fusion Table is currently importing rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

When repeatedly importing rows to a fusion Table via Apps Script, I run into cases where the rows are still being imported when I try and import more, this causes a general `internal Error`. Ideally I would check to see if the table is currently importing and only try and import when it is not.

Is there a function that exists in the Fusion Table API that reveals this information?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the situation yourself using some sort of 'flag' to know when the import function is finished (or not).

Script properties is the ideal tool to do so, example below.

```
function detectIfDone(){
  var done = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('done');
  if(done == 'done'){
    importData();
  }else{
    return;
  }
}

function importData(){
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('done','not yet');
  // do what you have to do
  Logger.log('import data');
  //when done
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('done','done');
}
```

Comment: Sadly the import itself is not a synchronous operation, it may still be importing after it returns from the import function, so the next import will continue and try and import during the previous import. The only way I have found is to throw a try-catch block into a do-while loop and only set my success variable once it actually succeeds. 

I still have the issue where I cannot tell if the import is complete before starting the next import, and can only tell that it was still importing once the next import throws an exception.